# Animation is not same like GIF

Tags: android, animation

[Viibe GIF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ta32kxpf4kynhcn/viibe-gif-okay_2x.gif?dl=0)

I have tried to develop this GIF in android. But my after development my app is not looking same like the GIF. The animation is not same like the GIF. I have added Ripple view effect. On the completion of the effect I have accept or delete the list item. What should I do?

Please help me to solve this problem.

This is my Adapter class for the first list.

```
    class ViibeAdapterOne(var context: Context, var viibeBOList : List<ViibeBO>, var viibeAdapterListenerOne: ViibeAdapterListenerOne)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViibeAdapterOne.ViibeViewHolder>() {

    private var iconstatus = 0

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViibeViewHolder {

        val layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.viibe_list, null)
        return ViibeViewHolder(layoutView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViibeViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.txtMessage.text = viibeBOList[position].message
        holder.txtSubmessage.text = viibeBOList[position].submessage

        holder.tick_icon.setOnClickListener{
            iconstatus = 1
            holder.rippleview.animate()
        }

        holder.cancel_icon.setOnClickListener{
            iconstatus = 2
            holder.rippleview.animate()
        }

        holder.rippleview.setOnRippleCompleteListener{
            if (iconstatus == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Accepted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                holder.childlayout.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.click_animation))
                viibeAdapterListenerOne.onClickListenerOne(holder.parentLayout, position, iconstatus)
            } else if (iconstatus == 2) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                holder.childlayout.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.click_animation))
                viibeAdapterListenerOne.onClickListenerOne(holder.parentLayout, position, iconstatus)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return viibeBOList.size
    }


    class ViibeViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        var txtMessage = itemView.txtMessage
        var txtSubmessage = itemView.txtSubmessage
        var cancel_icon = itemView.cancel_icon
        var tick_icon = itemView.tick_icon
        var parentLayout = itemView.parentLayout
        var childlayout = itemView.childlayout
        var rippleview = itemView.rippleview

    }

    interface ViibeAdapterListenerOne {
        fun onClickListenerOne(viewParent: View, position: Int, iconstatus: Int)
    }

}
```

In my Activity class I have called the deleteItem() in onClickListenerOne() overridden method of ViibeAdapterListenerOne interface :

```
private fun deleteItem(viewParent: View, position: Int, adapterStatus: Int, iconstatus: Int) {

    val anim: Animation

    if (iconstatus == 1) {
        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.slide_out_right)
    } else {
        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.slide_out_left)
    }
    anim.duration = 500
    viewParent.startAnimation(anim)

    Handler().postDelayed({
        if (adapterStatus == 1) {
            viibeBOListOne.removeAt(position)
            viibeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() //Refresh list
        } else if (adapterStatus == 2) {
            viibeBOListTwo.removeAt(position)
            viibeAdapterTwo.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }, anim.duration)
}
```

[Output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d5ebmywo8yo9dkp/20190730_145025.mp4?dl=0)

Comment: Also paste the output with above code

Comment: I have added the output. Please check.